# Chrome scrolls on tab key when form in iframe has focus

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, iframe

I have a iFrame which hosts an external site containing a form. If I press the tab keys on some of the form's textboxes, the whole browser tab scrolls down a page. Strangely enough, this doesn't do it on all of the form fields.

This only seems to happen in Chrome. I've tried it in Firefox and IE11, and this doesn't happen.

After it has scrolled down, the next form field does have focus - so the issues isn't that the next field is really far down.

The same happens when Javascript is disabled.

I'm having trouble diagnosing what this issue is. Is this a known issue with iframes? Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: yeah getting the same issue! Have u managed to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not with the same company now either, so will never know if they find a solution either I'm afraid.