# Chrome - Focus on iframe inputs causes unnecessary scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, backbone.js

I've spent days trying to find a solution to this but no luck. I'm aware that this might be a Chrome bug but I need help.

It's a web app built via backbones and underscore. I'm using Owl carousel to load in the iframes.

**Structure**:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="viewer-container">
        <!-- iframe loaded here -->
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <!-- Controls/Buttons -->
        next 
        previous
        menu
        fullscreen
    </div>
</div>
```

**Scenario**: When clicking on an input such as a select option, Chrome scrolls the iframe to God knows where. Weirdly though (can't confirm but guessing), it is worth mentioning this scroll behaviour could possibly happen if I use the controls, which is outside the iframe.

I have the same problem when pressing tab on Chrome only, as a result I've disabled the tab.

Firefox dev.edition seems to be only moving the select options to the edge of the screen but the iframe stays put. See 3rd screenshot.

The iframes contain a HTML page with inline JS and CSS.

I have tried:

- `Unbind / bind` the controls
- `Iframe.click`
- `Focus` on the iframe, input before and after using the controls
- `backface-visibility: hidden`

**Chrome version**: Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)
**Firefox version**: FF developr edition 47.0a2 (2016-03-21)
**OS**: All

Screenshots:

Before click:

[image: Default load]

After click:

[image: After clicking]

FF:

[image: Firefox]

```
var iframeDoc = $('#'+iframe.id).contents().get(0);
$(iframeDoc).on('click', function() {
//on('click, change, focus...
  $(iframeDoc).focus();
  $(iframeDoc).click();
  $(this).css({
    '-webkit-backface-visibility' : 'hidden', /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    'backface-visibility': 'hidden'
  });
});
```

Navigation:

```
/**
* Add events for carousel navigation. (Back and forward buttons)
*/
carouselControls: function(){
  var self = this;

  if($('#viewer-container').hasClass('fullscreen')) {
    $('.navigation-btn').hover(this.showControls, this.hideControls);
  }

  $('#navigation-btn-back').unbind('click').on('click', function(){
    self.slider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    self.loadFour();
  });

  $('#navigation-btn-forward').unbind('click').on('click', function(){
    self.slider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    self.loadFour();
  });
  $('#fullscreen-button').on('click', function(){
    self.slider.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
    self.loadFour();
  });
},
```

Related info:
[input tab focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169511/chrome-scrolls-on-tab-key-when-form-in-iframe-has-focus)
[chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439407)

What is the problem? Something with my code? The browsers? Is there anything I can do programmatically to prevent this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: following up: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597254&q=iframe&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on Chrome related to handling iframe contents.

It is now seems to be partly fixed with v50.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597254&q=iframe%20input%20focus&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified